# How to amplify audio signal made of two inputs?

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, lm386

I have made low-cost mosquito repellent, but I want to amplify the audio signal. The problem is, that in the source (https://electronicscheme.net/low-cost-mosquito-repellent/) the audio is made by oscillator and I cannot understand how to amplify this kind of audio signal, made of two sources Q and non-Q.

[image]

*Figure 1. [Elektor](http://elektor.com) schematic not attributed in linked article.*

I understand how normal audio from microphone is amplified, e.g. using 386 circuit (https://www.eleccircuit.com/lm386-audio-amplifier-circuit/) but in these, there are only "one input" to be amplified. How can I connect simple 386 audio amplifier to this oscillator (i.e. low cost mosquito repellent) (and then to the tweeter)?

Comment: Why do you want to amplify it? Are you using the correct piezo tweeter as noted in the schematic? Or are you, by any chance, trying to use a regular loudspeaker? (You can't. The 4047 won't be able to drive it and its frequency response won't extend into the ultrasonic region.)

Comment: That circuit uses 2 outputs from the oscillator to drive the piezo with more power. If you're going to use an external amplifier then just use one output and ignore the other.

Comment: Acoustic mosquito devices are essentially all scams, so not much point in building one except for fun. See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1948-7134.2010.00061.x

Comment: I am trying to amplify it because I use arduino to measure the ultrasonic sound, but it seems not to detect it. so I figured that maybe the sound was too weak and needs to be amplified.

Answer (score 1):

"differential amplifier" would be a good general searchword, but in this case I think you only have to amplify Q or /Q, as this circuit seems to use a bridge amplifier to drive the speaker.

Also, please note that since the page you linked provides little detail on this circuit, you have to do more work if you want to modify it. I would recommend searching for another similar circuit with a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to amplify the output with LM386, simply use one of the outputs. It does not even matter which one.

Comment: should I connect the other output to GND? is it ok to use piezo speaker or should I use another kind of speaker?

Comment: No, that will probably destroy the other output stage. Leave the other open.

Comment: Don't short the other unused output to GND - leave it open. LM386 is not meant to drive a piezo so piezo may not work. The speaker must be able to reproduce the high frequencies generated, but in general speakers made for humans don't need to play higher frequencies than about 20 kHz. Try finding a tweeter that can reproduce what you need. Although the original piezo without LM386 should have been loud enough.